# How to update json nested value and save file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following json file:

```
{"Event": "ev0000001_2019", 
     "Data": [{
        "eventSummary": {
            "awards": [{
                "awardName": "Foo",
                "categories": [{
                        "categoryName": "Best 1",
                        "type": ""}],
            }]} 
    }]}
```

I've done a function like this to **map nested values to be changed:**

```
def change(category):
    name_map = {
    "Best 1": "foo1",
    "Best 2": "foo2",
    "Best 3": "foo3"}

    if catName is None:
        return ''
    else:
        if catName in name_map:
            catName = name_map[catName]
        return catName
```

Now I need to **open a json file and apply those changes.** But I'm not being able to store the changes and save in a new file. Here's what I've being doing:

```
with open('./events.json', 'r') as file:
    json_file = json.load(file)

#iterate json
for events in json_file:
    for all_data in events['Data']:        
        for awards_names in all_data['eventSummary']['awards']:
            for categories_names in awards_names['categories']:
                #pass function to the categories:
                change(categories_names['categoryName'])

with open('./new_events.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_file, file, indent=4)
```

Comment: What isn’t working? Are the changes simply not appearing in the new file? Can you show an example of the data where there is a `None`? Having more of the data in general would be good. In any case, the problem appears to be that you simply aren’t saving the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are. This works

```
import json


def change(catName):
    name_map = {
        "Best 1": "foo1",
        "Best 2": "foo2",
        "Best 3": "foo3"}

    if catName is None:
        return ''
    else:
        if catName in name_map:
            catName = name_map[catName]
        return catName


with open('./events.json', 'r') as file:
    json_file = json.load(file)

# iterate json
for all_data in json_file['Data']:
    for awards_names in all_data['eventSummary']['awards']:
        for categories_names in awards_names['categories']:
            # pass function to the categories:
            categories_names['categoryName'] = change(categories_names['categoryName'])

with open('./new_events.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_file, file, indent=4)
```

### Source code changes for the case

After checking your source code deeper I see that there are 2 places with categories in the json structure we have.

So the final for should be

```
                for categories_names in awards_names['categories']:
                    categories_names['categoryName'] = change(categories_names['categoryName'])

                    for nomination in categories_names['nominations']:
                        nomination['categoryName'] = change(nomination['categoryName'])
```

Because nominations have their own categories, which were not been processed and now they are.

Comment: This changes the values... if I put:   
```
categories_names['categoryName'] = change(categories_names['categoryName'])
print(categories_names['categoryName'])
```

But the chages are'nt being saved on the file with neither whit

```
with open('./new_events.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_file, file, indent=4)
```

**or with**

```
file.seek(0)
file.write(json.dumps(json_file))
file.truncate()
```

Comment: The entire `change` function could be replaced with the definition of `name_map` and `return name_map.get(cat_name, ‘’)`.

Comment: `change` function returns CHANGED category name, but doesn't store it anywhere. To store it in the json you have to assign it like I did `categories_names['categoryName'] = change(categories_names['categoryName'])`

Comment: I did this Alexander. The thing is, doing that change ```categories_names['categoryName']``` but if I print ```json_file``` again, the ```categories_names['categoryName']``` are still the old ones. I need to change the ```json_file``` too in order to save the new file.

Comment: Can you post your code please? to https://gist.github.com/ or somewhere else

Comment: Here it goes @AlexandrShurigin [https://gist.github.com/isafloriano/edd5ad9665110bae39df3da14bb22ef2](https://gist.github.com/isafloriano/edd5ad9665110bae39df3da14bb22ef2)

Comment: @lela_rib check it now. Added a few more lines for your data

Comment: Oh... so simple in the end! Thanks for all the help @AlexandrShurigin